# Map marker placed some far distance to the corresponding co-ordinates

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps, android-location

Im working on google maps app, the problem is when i placed a marker for the latitude and longitude (i manually entered the gps co-ordinates), the marker shows some what correct place but not the exact one, it was placed some far distance to that corresponding co-ordinates. when i check these co-ordinates in Google maps [image: Google maps], it shows some road side place with two markers (Green and red) but in andorid mapview the marker matches equally to that green pin but i need to place the marker in red pin. Please help me from solving this issue.

Comment: Are you sure you manually entered the correct GPS coordinates? For example, if I enter `13.067851,80.248716`, I end up at the location of the red 'A' marker (more or less).

Comment: just for example i have given this. if you enter any gps co-ordinates in google map you will see the two pins green and red.

Comment: Well, I may be misunderstanding you, but in Google Maps the green marker is placed at the exact coordinates you enter in the search field. Hence, if you want it to show up on the position of the red marker, or any other location for that matter, you need to adjust the coordinates. You can make the marker show up anywhere you like, but you do need to provide the correct coordinates of course.

Comment: Yes, ofcourse i need to provide the correct co-ordinates, but when i place the marker for the same co-ordinates in ios or android default google maps, it pointed to the red pin not for green pin. so that im expecting to place the marker in red pin area.

Comment: The bitmap(png) used for the marker is really important. I am still trying to figure out exactly where the arrow, pointer should be on the image to pin point accurately.

Answer (score 0):

http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android

This link gives detail tutorial of working with maps. There you can find a simple calculation of putting pin on exact location.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Hardik, the above link samples also place the marker matches to green pin in Google maps. I need to place the pin matches to red pin 'A'